# Optimizing structure of arrays in C

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded

I'm trying to write up a structure to store coordinates for various graphic elements as well as some set and get functions. The values of the coordinates will change to accommodate the alternative fonts whenever the user changes their language selection. However the number of coordinate sets I need (integers I need to maintain) will be constant and is defined as numElements in the structure.

Please consider the following code. This is a sort of library I've made to support the other graphic drawing functions I use. It works as-is, but I'm in embedded systems so memory is at a premium and I would like to make a change but don't know how to make it work.

```
#define MAX_ELEM 20

typedef enum{TITLE, HEADER, TEXT, LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM}GRAPHIC_ITEMS;

typedef struct
{
     uint16_t x;
     uint16_t y;
}COORDINATES;

typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES coord[MAX_ELEM];
}GRAPHIC_COORD;

GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM] =
{
    { // TITLE
        1,
    },
    { // HEADER
        2,
    },
    { // TEXT
        14,
    }
};

void SetXCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t new_x, uint16_t elemNum);
void SetYCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t new_y, uint16_t elemNum);
uint16_t GetXCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t elemNum);
uint16_t GetYCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t elemNum);
```

I'd like to optimize the size of the COORDINATES arrays so they hold just enough information for the required number of elements. So the change to the code I have in mind would be like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES coord[numElements]; // changed size value here from MAX_ELEM to numElements
}GRAPHIC_COORD;
```

However when I make this change and try to compile I get errors saying that numElements is undefined. It seems to me that I shouldn't have to define the numElements in the type declaration and that defining it in the instance of the structure I declare should be enough. But obviously that's not the case. I assume I need to do something with dynamic memory allocation, but I haven't breached that subject deeply yet and am not sure what I need to do.

Note: the code I have provided above is much simplified. Part of my goal in doing it this way is to avoid having a large structure I need to maintain. In the actual application there are more like 30 graphic items each with 10-20 elements. If I were to do it as @Clifford or @Bastien suggest, then I will have 1000+ lines of structure/header file.

Note: numElements is only there to size the coord array within the GRAPHIC_COORD structure. If I were to do it as @Clifford or @Bastien suggest, I could omit the numElements member entirely which would simplify the structure. But the structure will still be absurdly long.

I'm working in Keil's uVision5 IDE with an STM32F103 chip on a custom board if that's of any importance.

Comment: You got the problem, as numElements is not defined, the compiler cannot know which size the table coord must be. You can use a linked list for your coordinates and allocate/deallocate memory when adding/removing coordinates. Are you familiar with Linked lists ?

Comment: Does your compiler support C99 flexible arrray members?

Comment: @martin Vaguely. I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it though. I'll always have the same number of coordinates (2 (x&y) per element per graphic item).  So the TITLE item has 1 elem, so 2 coordinates. The TEXT item has 14 elements, so 28 coordinates. It's just the values are initially calculated/set in-code and then will be retrieved later. Does that still mesh with what you were thinking?

Comment: @shawn I'm not sure? I'm using ARM's default compiler that is built in to Keil's IDE. How would I determine that?

Comment: @jvaille Are the initial coordinates hardcoded values or do you need to perform some calculation to derive them?

Comment: @dbush: a little column A, a little column B. Some of the values are based on hardcoded numbers, for example the start of the title area: (0,0). Others are calculated based on the font height that is currently being used, and will change whenever the user changes their language selection. So I have to recalculate them during run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

You are right, using dynamic memory allocation is certainly an option.

first, you have to use a pointer instead of a fixed size array in your structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES * coords;
}GRAPHIC_COORD;
```

Then, you could create the following function to allocate you coordinates dynamically:

```
void alloc_graphic_coords(GRAPHIC_COORD * graphic_coords, size_t graphic_coords_size)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < graphic_coords_size; i++)
    {
        /* can return null pointer if no memory available (should be handled) */
        graphic_coords[i].coords = (COORDINATES *) calloc(graphic_coords[i].numElements, sizeof(COORDINATES));
    }
}
```

then you can use it as follow:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
// ...
alloc_graphic_coords(graphicItemCoordinates, ARRAY_SIZE(graphicItemCoordinates));
```

The allocated memory should be freed at some point.

Be careful when using dynamic memory allocation. this could lead to memory leakage if not handled correctly.
You should definitely get familiar with it before implementing it in your project.

Furthermore, check the size of you heap memory in the keil IDE settings (should be big enough so that the coordinates can be stored in it).

**2.**

If you don't want to perform dynamic memory allocation, you could do something like that:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))

typedef enum{
    TITLE = 0,
    HEADER,
    LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM
}GRAPHIC_ITEMS;


typedef struct
{
     uint16_t x;
     uint16_t y;
}COORDINATES;


typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES * coords;
}GRAPHIC_COORD;


COORDINATES title_coordinates[] =
{
    {
        7, 9    // x & y coordinates
    },
};

COORDINATES header_coordinates[] =
{
    {
        5, 10    // x & y coordinates
    },
    {
        2, 3    // x & y coordinates
    }
};

GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[] =
{
    {
        ARRAY_SIZE(title_coordinates),
        title_coordinates
    },
    {
        ARRAY_SIZE(header_coordinates),
        header_coordinates,
    },
    // ... (add other coordinates here)
};

int main()
{
    printf("1rst x coordinate of title = %d", graphicItemCoordinates[TITLE].coords[0].x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**
You don't have to initialize the coordinates. for instance you can replace:

```
COORDINATES header_coordinates[] =
{
    {
        5, 10    // x & y coordinates
    },
    {
        2, 3    // x & y coordinates
    }
};
```

with:

```
#define HEADER_COORDS_SIZE (2)
COORDINATES header_coordinates[HEADER_COORDS_SIZE];
```

Comment: How would this work with the code I provided above? It seems to me like I would still have the same problem with the GRAPHIC_COORDS type. That is when I define the type I will have either an array with an undefined size (size = numElements) or where the arrays are oversized (size = MAX_ELEM). Is that not the case? Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated my answer if you want to take a look. you have to use a pointer instead of a fixed size array in your structure. this way, you can allocate the required amount of coordinates depending on your needs

Comment: well, this is the "long" way that I was trying to avoid. One of my goals in getting this going is to have it be really easy to maintain.  In the code I provided there are only 3 graphic items, but in the eventual application there will be more like 30 and some of those will have 20-30 elements each. Doing like you suggest would very quickly result in way too many structures and a very very long header file. The only reason I include the numElements memeber of the GRAPHIC_COORD structs is so I can size the coord[ ] array. If I do it like you suggest, I can omit that altogether.

Comment: In both cases (with and without dynamic memory allocation), you should keep the numElements struct member. It let you know how many elements are accessible using the corresponding COORDINATES pointer. If you have a lot of coordinates, then find a way to generate your header file automatically, by using a python script or even an excel macro for instance. good luck. your project seems challenging but interesting :)

Comment: Oooh! Excellent idea. Thank you. Also, it is! I'm completely redoing a remote controller's UI for a massage chair. I have a lot of freedom to do it "right", but that also comes with the responsibility of seeing your less-than-perfect ideas through haha. This might be one of them.

Comment: The OP says embedded system, so no, dynamic allocation isn't an option. Nor is VLA. Suggestion #2 is how you'd do in an embedded system.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic memory allocation and variable length-arrays are generally ill-advised on memory constrained devices since when an allocation fails, you have to be able to deal with it, and in this case there is probably nothing useful you could do.

If it is the case that for for each element, the coordinate array length is fixed, then dynamic allocation is entirely unnecessary in any case. Consider:

```
typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES* coord ;  // <<< pointer to coordinates array
}GRAPHIC_COORD;
```

Then:

```
COORDINATES title_coord[]  = { /*constant initialiser coords*/ } ;
COORDINATES header_coord[] = { /*constant initialiser coords*/ } ;
COORDINATES text_coord[]   = { /*constant initialiser coords*/ } ;
```

Then finally:

```
GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[] =
{
    { sizeof(title_coord)  / sizeof(GRAPHIC_COORD), title_coord  },
    { sizeof(header_coord) / sizeof(GRAPHIC_COORD), header_coord },
    { sizeof(text_coord)   / sizeof(GRAPHIC_COORD), text_coord   }
};

#define LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM (sizeof(graphicItemCoordinates) / sizeof(*graphicItemCoordinates))
```

Each `COORDINATES` array can then be of a different (albeit individually fixed) length.

You can simplify initialisers using macros perhaps - for example:

```
#define ITEM_COORDS_INIT( item ) {sizeof(item) / sizeof(GRAPHIC_COORD), (item)}
```

Then:

```
GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[] =
{
    ITEM_COORDS_INIT(title_coord),
    ITEM_COORDS_INIT(header_coord),
    ITEM_COORDS_INIT(text_coord)
};
```

Note that it is often better to let the size of arrays be determined by their initialiser rather then placing a value in the `[]`.  You can create a symbol for the number of elements by creating a macro as I have above for `LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM`.

Note also that if you intend that these structures should be placed in ROM - which you have rather more of than RAM typically, then you should declare them `static const`:

```
static const COORDINATES title_coord[]  = { /*constant initialiser coords*/ } ;
...
static const GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[] = ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding the storage-class modifier. I will do that! Please see my reply below to @Bastien and my edits to the original question. In the actual application, there will be ~30 graphic items with 10-20 elements each. If I do it as you suggest, I will have an absolutely huge structure to maintain. The file would quickly exceed 1000 lines of just structure. I also only have `numElements` there in order to size the `coord[]` array. If there's no way to do what I'm hoping for with or without dynamic memory, so be it. I'll take the hit on memory vs sheer # of lines of code

Comment: Additionally, in case I was unclear: in-application, the coordinates will be set after being calculated the first time a given graphic item is displayed. Then whenever a update-graphic-item function is called, I can just access the structure vs recalculating the coordinates to save processing power/time. You changed the storage class modifier to `const` there at the end so I wanted to make sure that was clear.

Comment: I also really don't want to get rid of the enumerated type. That makes accessing the big structure easy. To get the title coordinates I could call the function like so: `GetXCoord(TITLE, 1);` vs having to remember which graphic item corresponds to each index in the structure.

Comment: One more thing, if I let the size of the arrays be determined by their initializer, then I have to have an initializer. That would be as opposed to doing it like: `COORDINATES title_coord[NUM_TITLE_ELEM] = {0};` So on that note, what if I kept the enumerated type and structure I lay out. In addition I would define a size (i.e. number of elements) for each like: `#define NUM_TITLE_ELEM 1` and declare a `COORDINATES` struct for each item like above. That way I only have to edit the definitions, the number of elements, like in my initial question. Does that hold water?

Comment: @jvaille all your comments appear to be new questions rather than issues with the solution. Nothing in this answer precludes the enumeration. You need to initialise the data regardless of the solution so I don't see how this is any worse. To deal with the "thousands of lines" to maintain, I suggest you consider some sort of code generator that generates the structures from a more application specific description of the content. All I an illustrating here is the concept of a "jagged" array. I would suggest that it is the concept that is important, adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @jvaille The concept can be applied to dynamic allocation if that serves your needs. You simply assign the allocation to coord member, and initialise it programmatically. But the data is then necessarily in RAM, and if it is constant, that is a proiflegate use of a scarce resource.

Comment: Fair point, your solution does address the question. Thank you. What I suggest isn't any worse or better, just different as far as the size of the code on screen goes. `COORDINATES text_coord[NUM_TEXT_ELEM] = {0};` vs `COORDINATES text_coord[ ] = {{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}};` I like the software I write to be readable and understandable by the next guy, and the method you suggest where I provide the initializer list vs the size seems unnecessarily lengthy and would be confusing at first to someone who hadn't seen the code before.

Comment: Also, I suppose you're right regarding the enumerated type. I saw that you had redefined `LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM` as a macro, but if I provide the full initializer list inside my definition of `graphicItemCoordinates` then I don't necessarily need that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input!

I've settled on a solution that works in terms of on-screen code size and efficiency. This solution ensures that the volume of stored data is equal to the volume we actually need. This solution also comes across to me as readable by humans in addition to being easily understood. This is important as new team members may come and go; the less time spent on getting up the learning curve the better. Finally, I believe this code will be easily scalable in the inevitable case that new graphic items need to be created. Below is that code. Coming soon will be the script I'll use to maintain the full-size version of this long term. Cheers.

```
/* Type Declarations */
typedef enum{TITLE, HEADER, TEXT, LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM}GRAPHIC_ITEMS;

typedef struct
{
     uint16_t x;
     uint16_t y;
}COORDINATES;

typedef struct
{
    const uint16_t numElements;
    COORDINATES* coord;
}GRAPHIC_COORD;

/* Constants */
#define NUM_TITLE_ELEM     1
#define NUM_HEADER_ELEM    2
#define NUM_TEXT_ELEM      14

/* Variables */
COORDINATES titleCoord[NUM_TITLE_ELEM];
COORDINATES headerCoord[NUM_HEADER_ELEM];
COORDINATES textCoord[NUM_TEXT_ELEM];

GRAPHIC_COORD graphicItemCoordinates[LAST_GRAPHIC_ITEM] =
{
    { // TITLE
        NUM_TITLE_ELEM,
        titleCoord
    },
    { // HEADER
        NUM_HEADER_ELEM,
        headerCoord
    },
    { // TEXT
        NUM_TEXT_ELEM,
        textCoord
    }
};

/* Functions */
void SetXCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t new_x, uint16_t elemNum)
{
    graphicItemCoordinates[item].coord[elemNum].x = new_x;
}
void SetYCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t new_y, uint16_t elemNum)
{
    graphicItemCoordinates[item].coord[elemNum].y = new_y;
}
uint16_t GetXCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t elemNum)
{
    return graphicItemCoordinates[item].coord[elemNum].x;
}
uint16_t GetYCoord(GRAPHIC_ITEMS item, uint16_t elemNum)
{
    return graphicItemCoordinates[item].coord[elemNum].y;
}
```